# req.session.userId cannot be read in middleware function?

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies

I try to build a session authentication website. However when i try to parse the req.session.userId to my authentication middleware. The web page can't seems to realize the req.session.userId

Here is my code:

```js
const redirectLogin = (req,res,next) => {
    if (!req.session.userId) {
        res.redirect('/login')
    } else {
        next()
    }
}

app.post('/login',  async (req,res) => {
    const { email, password} = req.body;

    const user = await User.findOne({ email }).lean();
    
    if(!user) {
        return res.json ({status:'error', error:'Invalid email/password'})
    }
    if(await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
        // email, password combination is succesful
        req.session.userId = user._id
        return res.json ({status:'ok', user: req.session.userId})
    }
    res.json({ status: 'error', error: 'Invalid username/password' }) 
})

app.get('/home',redirectLogin,  (req,res) => {
    
    res.render('public', {title: 'Home'});
});
```

I want the code to authenticate the user and render the homepage. However, the redirectLogin seems to make it stay at the login page. I any tutorials i watched they have done the same and there isn't any problem.

Comment: What is the value of req.session? Is the req.session an empty object when you have an unauthenticated user?

Comment: Somehow i have corrected the problems. It seems to be the way i configure my session. Configures some of the value in cookie stored inside 'app.use(session())' and the code can't seems to function properly.